# Figure not displayed in pdflatex after exporting from lyx

Tags: lyx, pdf, lyx-layouts

I am able to add the figure in a lyx document, by using float and insert graphics. But when I view in the pdf, I don't see the figure in the inserted location. Instead I see the location of the file inside a blank box. See below.

[image]

I want to know why this is the case and any suggestions on how to fix it

Comment: normally it means that you have somewhere a `draft` option, or the pictures are not found, check the log-file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'll echo the request to check the log file.  But that file name almost looks like an absolute path `/Users/muthukum.../Documents//Thesis/Muthu/thesis/fig1_1.pdf` that got mangled in the conversion process.  Is that possible?

Comment: These are line in the log-file
"<fig1_1.pdf, id=22, 496.85625pt x 289.08pt>

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+cmtt on input line 1

59.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd

File: t1cmtt.fd 2022/07/10 v2.5l Standard LaTeX font definitions

) [5



{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}]

<6_Users_muthukumaranpanchaksaram_Documents__Thesis_Muthu_thesis_fig1_1.pdf, id

=29, 496.85625pt x 289.08pt>"

Comment: Also, in the log file I see that the draft mode is true. Should I change it to 'false'

Comment: You should be able to remove `draft` from `\documentclass[...]`.  `final` is the default option.

Comment: Duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77043221/figure-not-displayed-in-pdflatex-after-exporting-from-lyx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have checked by error the `Draft mode` in the  `LaTeX and LyX options` tab of the Graphics dialog:

[image: mwe]

You can check also if the image have this option in the  `Code Preview Pane`, (View menu):

```
\includegraphics[draft]{example-image}
```

Maybe you have set the option at a document level:

[image: mwe]

And then you must see in the Code Preview Pane some starting code as:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
```

Improbably, you could have this global option in the graphicx package, because set this is not trivial with LyX menus: Document → Settings → Local layout → type `provides graphicx 1` → Validate  → Apply, then in LaTeX preamble → type → `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` → Apply.

Finally, if there are not any `draft` option anywhere, but the image is not still showed the PDF, the file does not exist,  or you set the wrong path and/or the wrong filename.

At this respect, just some suggestions to debug this kind of issues:

- Place the images in the working directory.
- Be sure that you do not set absolute paths (`C:\etc\etc...`) in the Graphics tab, but only relative paths  (if you follow the above point, the relative path is  just the file name).
- Use short and simple file names (No spaces, no underscores, no extra dots, no tildes, no mix under-upper cases, no nothing). Although actual programs supposedly can handle well all of this, live is simply easier without having to deal with hypertrophied file names.